# custom user authentican by login in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have just start working with wordpress it is really cool.

I want to add user login functionality in my website I searched for it but really get confused with articles all I found about admin user management and other stuff. :(

**I** **just** **want** a simple login form where user can login with their credential and they can get access to website's other content. And user database will created hardcoded no registration require.

Can anyone please guide me what to surf for this functionality?
please help me here guys just suggetion would be enough. :)

Comment: WordPress already has a user account system. You can enable open-registration, or make accounts manually. I'm sure there are plugins for permissioning content.

Comment: @Alexander thanks you very nuch for suggetion. It was really helpful. and also really simple. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wordpress already provides user management. You can use members plugin to manage member. 
and you can also add security to wordpress selected content as per your requirement here by declaring privilages for perticular page.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add entry into user registration table, then you have to create your own table in database and put entries there. But its not a suggested way and maintaining users also little complicated one for you.

If you go with build in wordpress stuff it will reduce your work. Whatever customization you want to do it that you can do it through action hooks and filters.